# How to join two csv files in R and match the data from both tables?

Tags: r, csv, merge, left-join

I have two csv files

csv 1 has this data [image: This is the data of csv 1]

and csv 2 has this as its data
[image: Data of csv 2]

I want to add the episode review column from csv 2 to csv 1 with the correct episode name. How could I get this done? Any help is appreciated

EDIT: This is the code that got it work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

df1 = read.csv('NewEpisodes.csv', head = T)
df2 = read.csv('episodesReview.csv', head = T, )


dfLeft = df1 %>% left_join(df2, by=c("Episode.Name", "Show.Name"))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample data using `dput(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
final_csv = merge(csv_1, csv_2, by = c("Show.Name", "Episode.Name"))
```